# Removing non-0 priority MX records

Tags: email, email-server, mx-record, email-bounces

I have MX records set up as such:

0: domain.com (runs of the webhost, really bad)
1: GOOGLE
...
google

I somehow accidentally added the Google Apps mx servers, btu didn't change the priority 0 record.

Now weird stuff is happening. Most mail goes to the webhost server, but 2-5% of email goes to google apps.

What will happen if I remove the google apps ones?

Presumably, the 2-5% of emails are going there when the priority 0 record fails.

If i remove these 1..25 priority records, will the 2-5% of emails now start failing completely, or will they just be delivered with some delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's not clear what your end goal is here. If you want to have all your mail going to the webhost, then do what I say below. If you want your mail to go to google, then do the reverse - remove the web host MX. You need to choose *one* end destination for each mail domain.

A small bit of mail is going to google not because your web host is failing, but rather because some MTAs don't respect MX priority.

SMTP is very resilient to outages. Just remove the errant entries and all will be well. If the web host MX is down for a bit, sending MTAs will queue their mail and retry.